# Problem with regular expression in gawk ('\<' not working)

Tags: regular-expression, gawk

I am trying to get into bash a little bit. I was going through [this guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html) but the second example in [this subsection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_06_02.html#sect_06_02_03) on gawk doesn't seem to work.

The problem is this command:

```
ls -l | awk '/\<(a|x).*\.conf$/ { print $9 }'
```

It works only if I replace `\<` with a space. I also tried using `\y`, but no luck there either.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be here?

Thanks :)

Comment: I just tried it and it worked fine for me, what output do you get?

Comment: When I leave it as it is I get no output. If I use space instead of the `\<` it seems to work OK and I get the list of the `.conf` files that match.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `gawk` - not, for example, `mawk`?

Comment: @steeldriver You're right :) I am using `mawk`. Could you tell me what the difference is here?

Comment: `mawk` is "is smaller and much faster than `gawk`", but lacks some of its features (including some regex capability) - as you have discovered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GNU `awk` manual ([sec. 3.5](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators)) documents that the regex `\<` is gawk-specific and thus one should not expect it to work in other implementations.

According to [`man mawk`](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html), if you place a backslash in front of a nonspecial character, then the backslash is removed.  Thus, under `mawk`, `\<` is interpreted simply as an angle bracket character.

#### Examples

I simplified the regex to provide examples of the different behavior:

```
$ echo -e " a\n ab.conf\n <ac.conf" | gawk '/\<(a|x)/ { print}'
 a
 ab.conf
 <ac.conf
$ echo -e " a\n ab.conf\n <ac.conf" | mawk '/\<(a|x)/ { print}'
 <ac.conf
```

Again, `gawk` interprets `\<` as the beginning of a word while `mawk` interprets it simply as an angle bracket.

#### What does POSIX say about this issue

The [GNU `awk` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#GNU-Regexp-Operators) explains:

> If you place a backslash in a string constant before something that is
>   not one of the characters previously listed, POSIX awk purposely
>   leaves what happens as undefined.

In other words, in this case, the different `awk` interpreters are free to make their own decisions.